# Explanation of sparse coding

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, sparse-matrix

I'm studying the classification based on sparse coding and dictionary learning. I've read many documents but couldn't find an easy-to-understand one. As I understand, it's based on an optimization problem:
[image]

What's the meaning of the subscript (2)? And I guess the sign ||a|| means the amplitude of the vector?
And could you please suggest a good tutorial/introduction document for sparse coding? Thank you. (I tagged "image processing" and "machine learning" because I read somewhere that these fields use sparse coding. If not true, please comment and I'll remove the tags).

Comment: You can watch starting from this lecture on youtube playlist: [Image and video processing: From Mars to Hollywood with a stop at the hospital](https://youtu.be/h_fYIs0hdL0?list=PLZ9qNFMHZ-A79y1StvUUqgyL-O0fZh2rs)
I saw this lectures, seems enough for me, but they are not very deep.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. I'm going to check it

Comment: The video doesn't explain what the subscript is? I can understand the superscript of "2" but what's the subscript of "2"?

Comment: Asking for a tutorial is off topic (see the [help/on-topic], #4). I suggest you edit your question and remove that part, or it might be closed.

Comment: @lenhhoxung, https://rorasa.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/l0-norm-l1-norm-l2-norm-l-infinity-norm/

Comment: So it's just definition of Mean-Squared Error

Comment: @Olologin Exactly, now I understand the formula

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to dsp.stackexchange (question about algorithms used in signal processing)

Comment: I also work in that area. Could you give me the email. We can disscuss together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's just definition of Mean-Squared Error](https://rorasa.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/l0-norm-l1-norm-l2-norm-l-infinity-norm/)

Answer (score 0):

The subscript 2 means it's a l2 or Euclidean norm. [See here for detailed explaination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)).

[This](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/MLRG/sparseCoding.pdf) is an high-level overview of sparse coding,